# Python convert strings of bytes to byte array

Tags: python, character-encoding

For example given an arbitrary string. Could be `chars` or just random `bytes`:

```
string = '\xf0\x9f\xa4\xb1'
```

I want to output:

```
b'\xf0\x9f\xa4\xb1'
```

This seems so simple, but I could not find an answer anywhere. Of course just typing the `b` followed by the string will do. But I want to do this runtime, or from a variable containing the strings of byte.

if the given `string` was `AAAA` or some known `characters` I can simply do `string.encode('utf-8')`, but I am expecting the string of bytes to just be random. Doing that to `'\xf0\x9f\xa4\xb1'` ( random bytes ) produces unexpected result `b'\xc3\xb0\xc2\x9f\xc2\xa4\xc2\xb1'`.

There must be a simpler way to do this?

Edit:

I want to convert the string to bytes without using an encoding

Comment: Do you want to convert the string to bytes? It is not clear what the desired solution is... if you know it is a byte string without the b, you can do some string formatting. If you need it in bytes, you can call `bytes(string)`. Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606191/convert-bytes-to-a-string ?

Comment: Yes I want to simply convert the string to bytes

Comment: Okay I see your problem. You might need to use a raw string

Comment: The `bytes` function takes in a `string` and an `encoding`. Since the bytes I'm expecting are random, I don't want to pick an encoding for it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a working solution

```
import struct

def convert_string_to_bytes(string):
    bytes = b''
    for i in string:
        bytes += struct.pack("B", ord(i))
    return bytes
```

`string = '\xf0\x9f\xa4\xb1'`

`print (convert_string_to_bytes(string))`)

output:
`b'\xf0\x9f\xa4\xb1'`

Comment: b'\'\\x1e\\x03\\xcd\\xb6\\x93:\\x87\\xfc\\xcfp\\xfc\\xb7\\xba\\x8a\\x0es\\x81P\\xe1\\x1b\\n4a\\xe4"\\xdfA\\x8e\\x8a\\x15\\x18\\xb8\\x12\\xfcB/\\xea\\x83\\xd4\\x1dd\\xb8\\x14\\xd3\\xb9\\xfa\\x97B\\xfe\\x89\\xe1\\xff\\xbe\\x02\\xedY\\xc9pk\\\'\\xf8\\x1d9\\x1a\'' output is like this

Answer (score 5):

The Latin-1 character encoding trivially (and unlike every other encoding supported by Python) encodes every code point in the range 0x00-0xff to a byte with the same value.

```py
byteobj = '\xf0\x9f\xa4\xb1'.encode('latin-1')
```

You say you don't want to use an encoding, but the alternatives which avoid it seem far inferior.

The UTF-8 encoding is unsuitable because, as you already discovered, code points above 0x7f map to a sequence of multiple bytes (up to four bytes) none of which are exactly the input code point as a byte value.

Omitting the argument to `.encode()` (as in a now-deleted answer) forces Python to guess an encoding, which produces system-dependent behavior (probably picks UTF-8 on most systems except Windows, where it will typically instead choose something much more unpredictable, as well as usually much more sinister and horrible).