# Python string to shellcode byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, shellcode

I am trying to make a program that generates shellcode, in Python3, I need to to convert a string to the "\x00\x00" format, for example: "Hello" -> "\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f".
I cannot figure this out, if I try to just add "\\x" to "68", it does not work. I have tried to google everything I can, I thought this would be simple, but I'm stuck on it.

Comment: @Tomerikoo No, I don't know if i explained what I'm looking for well enough: b"\x68" works, if it is hard coded it works fine, I'm looking for a way to take a 68, and turn that into the equivalent of b"\x68"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python convert strings of bytes to byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51754731/python-convert-strings-of-bytes-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 1):

Emmm... Actually `"Hello"` is the same as `"\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f"`

If you want **just to print** that or whatever, you can do like that:

```
>>> print('"' + ''.join(['\\x'+hex(c)[2:] for c in "Hello".encode()]) + '"')
"\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f"
```

If you want to output bytes (you asked in comments):

```
>>> print('b\'' + ''.join(['\\x'+hex(c)[2:] for c in "Hello".encode()]) + '\'')
b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'
```

If you want to send bytes like b"Hello" somewhere, just send them. Yay.

Comment: This is close to what I'm looking for, I need that output to be b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'. Thats what im stuck on, if i use .encode() it outputs b'\\x48\\x65\\x6c\\x6c\\x6f'

Comment: `print('b\'' + ''.join(['\\x'+hex(c)[2:] for c in "Hello".encode()]) + '\'')` lol. Output will be like you want, but it is just an imitation.

Comment: That's not the way to do that...

Comment: You both realize that the preceding `b` has a special syntactic meaning and is not simply the letter `'b'`?

Comment: @tomerikoo to do what? He wants an output. So he gets it. Should he redefine the default output of bytes? If you send `b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'` to stdout with standard methods, he will get `b'Hello'`.

Comment: Youre right @Tomerikoo I just noticed that it wasnt right

Comment: @tomerikoo I know the meaning lol, but how you want to output it in other way?

Comment: To do any of that... Simply adding `'b'` to the start of a string doesn't make it a bytes object... It's a literal syntax... See the links I provided under the question to understand the differences...

Comment: I didn't propose to make a byte object. It is simply created like this: `"Hello".encode()`. I proposed how to output it...

Comment: "Hello".encode() -> b'Hello', I need b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f'

Comment: Man, I am speaking about it. b'Hello' and b'\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f' are the same. If you want to output it in hex here is the answer...

Comment: Exactly, @JackSmith you already have that, under the hood. It's just displayed as "Hello". The `b` in the start suggests it's actually a bytes object...

Comment: I dont have that. b ='"' + ''.join(['\\x'+hex(c)[2:] for c in "Hello".encode()]) + '"' Litterally is "\\x48\\x65\\x6c\\x6c\\x6f", If i send this with shellcode, the program will not understand that.

Comment: Great, just send b'Hello' in the shellcode. It will work :D

Comment: if it is hardcoded like: buf = b"\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f", that works, but i need to be able to create that "buf" in the code

Comment: AGAIN, it is created as `b"Hello"` which can be achieved by `"Hello".encode()`... `b"\x48\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f" == b"Hello"`

Comment: I'm sorry, i see what you are saying. Youre right. I didnt assume that they were seen as the same by the computer.

Comment: The problem was i thought i had tried that earlier and it didnt work, it mustve been something else off. Apologies

Comment: @JackSmith No worries, we are here to help. Just try to isolate the problem and find out what is the REAL error and edit the question accordingly

Comment: @jack-smith it is fine, bro